# Jenkins pipeline access variable created by spawned shell

Tags: git, jenkins, branch

I'd like to be able to trigger a Jenkins multibranch pipeline (called project A) from a another non-multibranch pipeline project (called project B).

I want any branch in project B to trigger a build in the corresponding branch in A. I am thinking the best way to do this is in B's Jenkinsfile, determine the current branch. Unfortunately the BRANCH_NAME variable is not available to standard (non-multibranch) Jenkins pipelines. I know I can determine the branch by spawning a shell and calling "git branch" like so:

```
sh '''
  MYBRANCH=`git branch`
'''
```

But, how can I make a shell variable available to its parent Pipeline??

In the end, from project B, I will (hopefully) end up calling:

```
 build job: "project-A/${MYBRANCH}", wait: false
```

** **UPDATE** **

I ended up solving my issue by going down a different route.

I put both repositories (A & B) into a single multi-branch pipeline Job. By doing this, the current branch of B is available as a variable (and I can modify it as needed), then trigger a build of repo A. It seems to be working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Jenkins to capture the stdout of your command and assign in to a variable:

```
def MYBRANCH = sh( script: 'git branch', returnStdout: true)
```

In declarative, you will need to wrap this in a `script{}` step. Depending on where and how you are using the MYBRANCH variable, you may have to declare the variable elsewhere to make sure it is in scope in the right places.

Comment: It almost worked. Except the branch name that was returned is '* (detached from ddd42e1)'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling a job from a job, then [as illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43117970/6309), you can pass variables in parameter:

```
 build job:'/Folder/JobB',parameters: [string(name: 'BRANCH', value: "${params.BRANCH}")], propagate: false
}
```

But if not, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43869686/6309): try and use the [CopyArtifact plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to write into a file and copy it accross job/workspace.