# Terraform remote state in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

am working on a declarative Jenkins pipeline for Terraform deployments. I want to have the terraform state stored remotely in my s3  I get an error

```
terraform apply -input=false ow.plan
[31mFailed to load Terraform configuration or plan: open ow.plan: no such file or directory
```

Any suggestions?

Here's my code:

```
 pipeline {

    agent any

   tools {
        "org.jenkinsci.plugins.terraform.TerraformInstallation" "terraform"
    }

   parameters {
    choice(name: 'action', choices: 'create\ndestroy', description: 'Create/update or destroy the eks cluster.')
    string(name: 'cluster', defaultValue : 'demo', description: "EKS cluster name;eg demo creates cluster named eks-demo.")
    string(name: 'vpc_network', defaultValue : '10.0', description: "First 2 octets of vpc network; eg 10.0")
    string(name: 'num_subnets', defaultValue : '3', description: "Number of vpc subnets/AZs.")
    string(name: 'instance_type', defaultValue : 'm4.large', description: "k8s worker node instance type.")
    string(name: 'num_workers', defaultValue : '3', description: "k8s number of worker instances.")
    string(name: 'api_ingress_cidrs', defaultValue : '0.0.0.0/0', description: "k8s api ingress cidrs; space delimited list.")
    string(name: 'jenkinsfile', defaultValue : '', description: "Jenkins credential that provides the AWS access key and secret.")
    string(name: 'region', defaultValue : 'eu-west-1', description: "AWS region.")
  }

  environment {
        TF_HOME = tool('terraform')
        TF_IN_AUTOMATION = "true"
        PATH = "$TF_HOME:$PATH"
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = credentials('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = credentials('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
        TF_VAR_access_key = credentials('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
        TF_VAR_secret_key = credentials('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    } 





  stages {

    stage('Setup') {
      steps {
        script {
          currentBuild.displayName = "#" + env.BUILD_NUMBER + " " + params.action + " eks-" + params.cluster
          plan = params.cluster + '.plan'
        }
      }
    }

    stage('TF Plan') {
      when {
        expression { params.action == 'create' }
      }
      steps {
        dir('infra/terraform/eks'){   
        script {
          withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', 
            credentialsId: awsCredentialsId,
            accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',  
            secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]) {

            // Format cidrs into a list array
            def ips = '["' + params.api_ingress_cidrs.replaceAll(/\s+/,'\",\"') + '"]'

            sh """
              terraform init
              terraform workspace new ${params.cluster} || true
              terraform workspace select ${params.cluster}
              terraform plan \
                -var cluster-name=${params.cluster} \
                -var vpc-network=${params.vpc_network} \
                -var vpc-subnets=${params.num_subnets} \
                -var inst-type=${params.instance_type} \
                -var num-workers=${params.num_workers} \
                -var 'api-ingress-ips=${ips}' \
                -out ${plan}
            """
          }
        }
        }
      }
    }

    stage('TF Apply') {
      when {
        expression { params.action == 'create' }
      }
      steps {
        script {
          input "Create/update Terraform stack eks-${params.cluster} in aws?" 

          withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', 
            credentialsId: awsCredentialsId, 
            accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',  
            secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]) {

            sh """
              terraform apply -input=false ${plan}
            """
          }
        }
      }
    }

    stage('TF Destroy') {
      when {
        expression { params.action == 'destroy' }
      }
      steps {
        script {
          input "Destroy Terraform stack eks-${params.cluster} in aws?" 

          withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', 
            credentialsId: awsCredentialsId, 
            accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',  
            secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]) {

            sh """
              terraform workspace select ${params.cluster}
              terraform destroy -auto-approve
            """
          }
        }
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073809/jenkins-pipeline-share-information-between-jobs

Comment: you can share the files between stages. See above link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins pipeline share information between jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073809/jenkins-pipeline-share-information-between-jobs)